# Why does this Java regex fail?

Tags: java, regex

In my Java code, I would like to match strings such as:

```
1m
112m
10million
9Million
```

I also want to match stuff like "100k". The following works for the "k" but not for the "m". Why is that?

```
if (moneyExp.matches("[-+]?\\d+[kK]")) {
    String modMoney = moneyExp.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
    modMoney += "000";
    mw.hashX.remove("Amount");
    mw.doublePut("Amount", modMoney, 1);
    tagMap = mw.hashX;
} else if (money.matches("[-+]?\\d+[mM]")) {
    String modMoney = moneyExp.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
    modMoney += "000000";
    mw.hashX.remove("Amount");
    mw.doublePut("Amount", modMoney, 1);
    tagMap = mw.hashX;
}
```

Comment: Probably because you seem to use `moneyExp` for `k` matches and `money` for m matches.

Comment: matches tries to match the whole string so your regex fails to match `10million`

Comment: Your `else` condition has `money.matches` instead of `moneyExp`. Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works only with 100k, 34m etc. because the `match()` need to match whole string to return `true`. So you can try with:

```
moneyExp.matches("\\b[-+]?\\d+[kK](\\w+)+?\\b"); // for k
moneyExp.matches("\\b[-+]?\\d+[mM](\\w)+?\\b");  // for m
```